# How do I read strings in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, network-programming, midp

I'm using the MIDP 2.0 (JSR 118) and I just noticed that there is no reader for strings in J2ME.

Does anyone know how you are supposed to read Strings from an `InputStream` or `InputStreamReader` in a platform independent way (i.e. between two java enabled cell phones of different models)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively have a look at [`DataInputStream.readUTF()`](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUTF()).

It does required that the string being read off the InputStream be encoded appropriately (as in by a corresponding [`DataOutputStream.writeUTF(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String))) so it might not be what you're looking for - but it does work across different phones/models etc.

Answer (score 5):

Which profile are you using? The MID profile in JSR 118 specifies [InputStreamReader](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) (not StringReader, but that wouldn't help you read from an InputStream anyway).

EDIT: To reflect the change to the question :)

You use InputStreamReader.read(char[], int, int) and when you've read all you want to, create a new string from a char array. If you want to read a line at a time as you would from BufferedReader, you basically need to implement the functionality of BufferedReader yourself (keeping a buffer of "read but not consumed" chars) and keep reading until you hit a line break.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using MIDP 2.0 (JSR 118). Edited my question. I want to know if there is some way to read strings from any given InputStream.

Answer (score 3):

Well... I know this was a LONG time ago.

You need to do exactly what John said, and it is VERY simple. It almost took me 5 hours to figure this one out the first time...

I still wonder why j2ME didn't include something as essential as the `BufferedReader` method for sockets, it's not like the freakin cellphones will crash with it... and yes, I don't give a rat's ass if my app runs 1ms slower than it should.

(I'm just going to put the relevant code, I assume you know how to form classes and import the required libraries)

```
ServerSocketConnection listener
    = (ServerSocketConnection)Connector.open("socket://:1235");
System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
StreamConnection server = listener.acceptAndOpen();
InputStream is = server.openInputStream();

//Now comes the fake BufferedReader equivalent part

int ch = 0;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

while ((ch = is.read()) != -1){
    sb.append((char)ch);
    if(sb.charAt(sb.length()-1) == 13 ) {
       //Carriage return was received or ENTER was pressed
       break; //Exit loop and print input
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `is.read()` method will lock the thread till new input is received from the user ONE BYTE AT A TIME. This means if you use telnet to test, each keystroke will make the loop iterate once, hence, we simply concatenate char by char in a `StringBuffer` until char 13 is received.

```
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

I hope this helps people trying to do a socket server on j2ME. I already crafted a fully functional multithreaded version of this for blackberry, in case anyone needs it.

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to provide an example of this?

You use `InputStreamReader.read(char[], int, int)` and when you've read all you want to, create a new string from a char array. If you want to read a line at a time as you would from `BufferedReader`, you basically need to implement the functionality of BufferedReader yourself (keeping a buffer of "read but not consumed" chars) and keep reading until you hit a line break.