# how to read string line by line in j2me

Tags: java-me

how can i read one line from string ??? i have string like this :

> hello ; boy ; sun
>
> welcome;google;pink

how can i read first line only ?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String originalString="hello ; boy ; sun\nwelcome;google;pink";
String firstLine=originalString.substring(0,originalString.indexOf('\n'));
```

Answer (score 2):

be aware that some applications actually use \r\n instead of \n to indicate new lines

Answer (score -1):

See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200239/how-do-i-read-strings-in-j2me), but I like [this solution](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?124711-import-java.io.StringReader-Cannot-be-resolved!!!) better:

```
final InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader( new ByteArrayReader( string.getBytes() ) );
```

Comment: Uh, yeas.  I was giving an alternative way of doing it by reading the string like a stream.  I realize J2ME doesn't have StringReader, so this is another way of doing it.

Comment: How did this guy get so much rep!?

Comment: If you don't think my solution is a good one, then that's fine, but I presented an alternate way of reading a string line by line in J2ME, as if it was a file.  What's your problem?  Why don't you think my answer is relevant?  because I didn't spell out the loop to read from the stream?  I thought that was kinda obvious.