# J2ME alternative for java.io.BufferedReader?

Tags: java, java-me, bufferedreader

I got a code from net and it uses

```
imports java.io.BufferedReader 
imports java.io.PrintWriter
```

This code is in JAVA SE. But I need to do the same in J2ME(JAVA ME). But it doesn't have BufferedReader and PrintWriter?

What can be used instead of BufferedReader and PrintWriter?

Comment: Maybe you'll want to look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200239/how-do-i-read-strings-in-j2me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) is there because of readLine method you can replace it by [InputStreamReader](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) and use a method like:

```
    public String readLine(Reader reader) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();
        int c = reader.read();

        while (c != -1 && c != '\n') {
            line.append((char)c);
            c = reader.read();
        }

        if (line.length() == 0 && c == -1) {
            return null;
        }

        return line.toString();
    }
```

If [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) is there because of print methods you can replace it by [PrintStream](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/java/io/PrintStream.html).

Comment: I just came across this answer (yeah, I still have to work with J2ME). There is a bug in this snippet - it returns `null` on first empty line. Shouldn't the if condition be `line.length() == 0 && c == -1` ?

Comment: considering an empty line as one just containing a '\n', yes, it will return null on first empty line